# Co variance of isotopes in geochemical amplications

Tags: geochemistry, isotopic

I recently heard that the d98Mo isotope is not different from the d238U isotope in redox processes e.g. in black shale events. But I can't find any evidence except the figure from Zhang et al. unfortunately,
2018:

[image]

But I know that the correlation is not really recognisable and the explanation is missing:D Can you give me literature or have an explanation at hand?

Comment: You might be interested in this: [*Uranium and molybdenum isotope evidence for an episode of widespread ocean oxygenation during the late Ediacaran Period*](https://www.uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/handle/10012/13781).

Comment: There is also: [*An expanded shale d98Mo record permits recurrent shallow marine oxygenation during the Neoarchean*](https://uwaterloo.ca/scholar/bkendall/publications/expanded-shale-d98mo-record-permits-recurrent-shallow-marine-oxygenation) and [*Anomalous molybdenum isotope trends in Upper Pennsylvanian euxinic facies: Significance for use of d98Mo as a global marine redox proxy*](https://asu.elsevierpure.com/en/publications/anomalous-molybdenum-isotope-trends-in-upper-pennsylvanian-euxini-2).

Comment: This has a little more information than the previous link [*Anomalous molybdenum isotope trends in Upper Pennsylvanian euxinic facies: Significance for use of δ98Mo as a global marine redox proxy*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S000925411200232X).

Comment: Out of interest, what does the d or δ in front of the isotope mean, as δ98Mo or d98Mo?

Comment: I mean your Delta, i dont know how to tipe it:)

Comment: I just copied δ from the operating system character map & inserted it here.